# MATLAB: Correlation with a seed region

Tags: matlab, correlation, bsxfun

By default, all built-in functions for computing correlation or covariance return a matrix.  I am trying to write an efficient function that will compute the correlation between a seed region and various other regions, but I do not need the correlations between the other regions. I assume that computing the full correlation matrix would therefore be inefficient.

I could instead compute a the correlation matrix between each region and the seed region, choose one of the off diagonal points and store it, but I feel like looping in this situation is also inefficient.

To be more concrete, each point in my 3-dimensional space has a time dimension. I am attempting to compute the mean correlation between a given point and all points in space within a given radius.  I want to repeat this procedure hundreds of thousands of times, for many different radius lengths, and so on, so I would like for this to be as efficient as possible.

So, what is the best way to compute the correlation between a single vector and several others, without computing correlations that I will just ignore?

Thank you,
Chris

EDIT: Here is my code now...

```
function [corrMap] = TIME_meanCorrMap(A,radius)
% Even though the variable is "radius", we work with cubes for simplicity...
% So, the radius is the distance (in voxels) from the center of the cube an edge.
denom = ((radius*2)^3)-1;
dim = size(A);
corrMap = zeros(dim(1:3));
for x = radius+1:dim(1)-radius
    rx = [x-radius : x+radius];
    for y = radius+1:dim(2)-radius
        ry = [y-radius : y+radius];
        for z = radius+1:dim(3)-radius
            rz = [z-radius : z+radius];
            corrCoefs = zeros(1,denom);
            seed = A(x,y,z,:);
            i=0;
            for xx = rx
                for yy = ry
                    for zz = rz
                        if ~all([x y z] == [xx yy zz])
                            i = i + 1;
                            temp = corrcoef(seed,A(xx,yy,zz,:));
                            corrCoeffs(i) = temp(1,2);
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            corrMap = mean(corrCoeffs);
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT: Here are some more times to supplement the accepted answer.
Using bsxfun() to do normalization, and matrix multiplication to compute correlations:

```
tic; for i=1:10000                                                                
    x=rand(100);
    xz = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,x,mean(x)),std(x));
    cc = xz(:,2:end)' * xz(:,1) ./ 99;
end; toc
Elapsed time is 6.928251 seconds.
```

Using zscore() to normalize, matrix multiplication to compute correlations:

```
tic; for i=1:10000                                    
    x=rand(100);                                          
    xz = zscore(x);                                       
    cc = xz(:,2:end)' * xz(:,1) ./ 99;
end; toc
Elapsed time is 7.040677 seconds.
```

Using bsxfun() to normalize, and corr() to compute correlations.

```
tic; for i=1:10000                                    
    x=rand(100);
    xz = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,x,mean(x)),std(x));
    cc = corr(x(:,1),x(:,2:end));
end; toc
Elapsed time is 11.385707 seconds.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to improve upon the `for` loop that you are currently employing. The correlation compuattions can be parallelized using matrix multiplications if you have sufficient RAM. However, it will require you to unwrap your 4-dimensional data matrix A into a different shape. most likely you are dealing with 3-dimensional voxelwise fMRI data, in which case you'll have to reshape from [x y z time] matrix to an [index time] matrix. I will assume you can deal with that reshaping. Once you have your `seed` timecourse [Time by 1] and your `target` timecourses [Time by NumTargets] ready, you can perform some much more efficient computations.

A quick way to efficiently compute the desired correlation is using the `corr` function in MATLAB. This function will accept 2 matrix arguments and it will quite efficiently compute all pairwise correlations between the columns of argument 1 and the columns of argument 2, e.g.

```
T = 200; %time samples
N = 20;  %number of other voxels

seed = randn(T,1);     %data from seed voxel
targets = randn(T,N);  %data from target voxels

%here is the for loop method
tic
for n = 1:N
   tmp = corrcoef(seed, targets(:,n));
   tmpcc = tmp(1,2);
end
looptime = toc;

%here is the parallel method
tic
cc = corr(seed, targets);
matrixtime = toc;
```

On my machine, the parallel operation in `corr` is faster than the loop method by a factor proportional to T*N.

It is possible to go a little faster than the `corr` function if you are willing to perofrm the underlying matrix operations yourself, and in any case it is worth knowing what they are. The correlation between two vectors is basically a normalized dot product, so using the conventions above you can compute the correlations in the following way

```
zseed = zscore(seed);  %normalize the seed timecourse by z-scoring
ztargets= zscore(targets);  %normalize the target timecourses by z-scoring
ztargets = ztargets';      %flip columns and rows for convenience
cc2 = ztargets*zseed./(T-1);    %compute many dot products with one matrix multiplication
```

The code above is basically what the `corr` function will do which is why it is much faster than the loop. Note that most of the operation time is in the `zscore` operations, and you can  improve on the performance of the `corr` function if you efficiently compute the `zscore` using the `bsxfun` command. For now, I hope this gives you some direction on how to compute a correlation between a seed timecourse and many target timecourses without having to loop through and compute each one separately.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you! And the fact that you deduced the nature of my data from just my description and code was a nice added touch.

Comment: Well, I have worked on similar problems in the past, so it was not too  unlikely a guess. Glad to help!